# Maximising the difference between elements in an array

Tags: python, algorithm

An array of `N` integers is divided into two parts of `K` and `N-K` elements such that the difference between the sum of the elements in those two parts is to be maximised.

```
TEST CASES
N=5, K=2
arr = [8 4 5 2 10]
O/P: 17 because (8+5+10) − (4+2) = 23 − 6 = 17.

N=8, K=3
arr= [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
O/P: 2 because (1+1+1+1+1)-(1+1+1)=2
```

What I am trying to do is first sum all the elements in the array. Then, find the sum of smallest `K` elements in the array and subtract twice of the latter from the first one.

```
def smallestKSum(arr,K):
    # returns the sum of the smallest K now. in the array
    arr.sort()
    r=0
    for i in range(K):
        r=r+arr[i]
    return r

N,K = map(int,raw_input().split())
arr = map(int,raw_input().split())
s = sum(arr)
print s-(2*smallestKSum(arr,K))
```

The above solution works fine on the above test cases, but still it says `Wrong Solution` when I try to submit it. You may check out the problem at this [link](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MAXDIFF).

Is there something that I am missing ? And can I find the sum of smallest `K` nos without sorting the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, kid should carry more weight to maximize difference.

For example, if weights are [1,2,3,4], k is 3, kid should take [2,3,4].

(2+3+4) - (1) = 8

not, [1,2,3]

(1+2+3) - (4) = 1

```
def smallestKSum(xs, k):
    xs = sorted(xs)
    return max(
        abs(sum(xs[k:]) - sum(xs[:k])),
        abs(sum(xs[-k:]) - sum(xs[:-k]))
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

The test case you are missing is k might be greater than n-k.

so make k as min(n-k,k)

Why don't you find the sum of the remaining elements in the same function instead of summing up all and again substracting. 
Try this:

```
def smallestKSum(arr,K):
    # returns the sum of the smallest K now. in the array
    arr.sort()
    r=0
    s=0
    for a in arr[:K]: 
       r += a 
    for a in arr[K:]: 
       s += a
    return s-m
```

The return value is your required answer

Comment: Why doing `for in in range(K)` when there are slices in python?

Comment: @mishik sorry I'm no good with python. I just found out his mistake

Comment: Use this: `for i in range(K)` -> `for a in arr[:K]: r += a`
`for i in range(n-k)` -> `for a in arr[K:]: s += a`